# How to install Windows 10 on a pen drive using ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, windows

I have the ISO for windows 10 and I want to install it **into** a pen drive. I don't want to have a bootable pen drive to install windows in another machine, I want to have a bootable pen drive that actually runs windows **from** the pen driver (windows to go).

There are some tools that make that on windows, like WinToUSB but I can't find a way to do this from Ubuntu once I don't have windows yet to run WinToUSB. I've tried to run WinToUSB using Wine, but it does't work.

Comment: Not a thing you can do...  and if you can, won't be easy. If windows to go boots the same as the installers then there's a chance: installing GRUB on your USB (I've done it with windows 7/10 installers) and add the appropiate GRUB entry.

Comment: Windows 10 is designed to obviate this. Therefore, Linux folks don't invest time in development.